# No route matches [DELETE] "/" -- routes problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, crud, http-delete

I'm trying to make a button work deleting a product from my app, but when i do it it show the error:

> No route matches [DELETE] "/"

I search for this problem but i couldn't find something that really helped me.

This is my routes file :

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

    resources :despensa, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

    root to: "despensa#index"
end
```

This is my Controller:

```
class DespensaController < ApplicationController
    
    def index
        @produtos = Produto.order :nome
        @produto_menor_quantidade = Produto.order(:quantidade).limit 1    
    end

    def create
       produto = params.require(:produto).permit(:nome, :quantidade, :unidade_de_medida)
       Produto.create produto
       redirect_to root_path
    end

    def destroy
        id = params[:id]
        Produto.destroy id
        redirect_to root_path
    end
end
```

And this is the part of the button:

```
  <% @produtos.each do |produto| %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= produto.nome%></td>
            <td><%= produto.quantidade %></td>
            <td><%= produto.unidade_de_medida %></td>
            <td><%= button_to "Remover", despensa_path(id), method: :delete ,
             class:"btn btn-danger",
             :onclick => "return confirm('Tem certeza que deseja remover #{produto.nome} da despensa?')" %>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <% end %>
```

And finally, this are how my routes looks like:

```
despensa_index_path POST    /despensa(.:format) 
despensa#create

new_despensa_path   GET /despensa/new(.:format) 
despensa#new

despensa_path   DELETE  /despensa/:id(.:format) 
despensa#destroy

root_path   GET /   
despensa#index
```

I saw something about jquery, but im not sure if that is the problem, actually i really dont know what is happening here. It was supossed to erase the product when u click the button "remover".

Comment: `despensa_path(id)` this should be `despensa_path(produto.id)`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to remove calling DELETE on`despensa_path(id)` but you haven't defined `id` anywhere on your code. Probably `id` gets evaluated into `nil` so the route goes blank.

You could change your code to get `despensa_path(produto.id)`

Besides, as with another post, `despensa` is *singular* and resources is meant for *plural* nouns so things could get a bit weird.